# How to use the iOS 5 SDK with Theos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, tweak

I recently wanted to make a tweak which uses the iOS 5 Twitter framework so I got the headers from my Xcode.app and pasted them in /opt/theos/include/Twitter/
However when I add Twitter as a framework in my makefile ld shows me an error about not finding the twitter framework. How can I solve this problem? Is there any way to port the iOS 5 SDK to theos without screwing up things? Thanks.

And if anyone wants to see the code being compiled here is a Github project which I tried to compile but failed with the same error. The link is https://github.com/mergesort/QuickTweet

~iHackerMe

Comment: You don't need the headers for the Twitter framework if all you want to do is to tweet.

Comment: Thanks a lot leonnears but it dosen't tweet without the frameworks! By the way I follow your blogs! :)